# how do i get master recurrence appointment EWS?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

My appointment is on recurring for a week. By using below line of code:

```
FindItemsResults<Appointment> results = folder.findAppointments(cView);
```

Results are returning all the occurrences of same appointment where I just want only one entry in it for each appointment. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the FindItems Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.finditems(v=exchg.80).aspx instead of the FindAppointments method that will just return all the appointment objects un-expanded (eg meaning for recurring appointments you will just get the Master Instance).

Comment: Hi Glen, Thanks it works. And one more doubt I have appointment.getRecurrence().getNumberOfOccurrences() is returning null. Any idea how should I get it?

Comment: The Recurrence data isn't return by FindItems so you need to do a Load on the item first or more efficiently do a loadpropertiesformItems https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/03/16/loading-properties-for-multiple-items-with-one-call-to-exchange-web-services/ and do this for the whole batch of item

Comment: thanks glen, One more question i have that my appointment is on weekly pattern for e.g. Monday and Tuesday so how should i get this data? I searched but i didn't get anything.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.recurrence.weeklypattern.daysoftheweek(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks Glen.. Thank you Very much.